# Moving files based on filename

Tags: bash, filenames, move

I have folder with .tif files that I want to move based on their filename to a folder with same name.
Example file 123456789_002.tif --> dir 113456789 .

How do I get the first part of the file before the _ and use it to move the files?

Answer (score 1):

If the filename is stored in the variable `$filename`, you can get the portion before the first underscore `_` using `${filename%%_*}` in bash and similar shells.

A little script might look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# loop over all tif files
for filename in *.tif ; do
    # extract portion before _
    dirname="${filename%%_*}"
    # ensure destination folder exists
    mkdir -p "$dirname/"
    # move the file
    mv "$filename" "$dirname/" 
done
```

Comment: This script makes the folder123456789 and add a. at end. The script did not move file 123456789_002.tif in to the folder. Also if I have example dir 123566891 and want to move file 1234567891_001.tif into if. 

This is script i am running

#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter the file path"
Read path
cd $path
# loop over all tif files
for filename in *.tif ; do
    # extract portion before _
    dirname="${filename%%_*}"
    # ensure destination folder exists
    mkdir -p "$dirname/"
    # move the file
    mv "$file" "$dirname/" 
done

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The script I posted does not add "a"s anywhere, and it does move files. Yours seems identical except for the reading the path at the start and that I accidentally wrote `$file` instead of `$filename` near the end when first posting, but I have fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the _more_stuff with nothing, leaving you with the first part. E.g. with the filename in variable i, say firstpart=${i/_?*/}

```
for i in *_*.tif; do 
    fp="${i/_?*/}"
    mkdir "$fp" 2>/dev/null # ignore errors else this will complain for 2nd etc files
    mv "$i" "$fp"
done
# do remaining .tif files, with no "_"
for i in *.tif; do 
    fp="${i/.tif/}"
    mkdir "$fp" 2>/dev/null # ignore errors else this will complain for 2nd etc files
    mv "$i" "$fp"
done
```

Comment: If a file dose not have _ would it be posable to move it as well to the folder? i test the script and it worked well

Comment: sure, added a "no _" section.